# Reading Docx file content in jsp using apache POI org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

Tags: java, jsp, ckeditor, apache-poi

Hi I want to show Microsoft docs content to the web page using Apache POI library

This is working fine with as a java application.

but application is throwing exception on jsp

PS

Below is my work so far

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument" %>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="get" action="FileServlet"
    style="height: 78px;">
    <input type="file" name="xls_filename" align="top"
        onchange="form1.submit()">
</form>
<%
    String filename = request.getParameter("xls_filename");

    if (filename != null && !filename.equals("")) {
%>
<br>You chose the file
<%=filename%>.

<br>It's contents are:
<%
    InputStream fs = null;
        String fileData;

        XWPFWordExtractor extractor = null;

        try {
            fs = new FileInputStream(filename);

            XWPFDocument hdoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fs));

            extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(hdoc);

            fileData = extractor.getText();
            System.out.println(fileData);
            // document.add(new Paragraph(fileData));
            System.out.println(" pdf document created");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //  document.close();
        }
%>
<%
    }

%>
</body>
```

Stacktrace:

```
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

above is complete stack trace and errors shown as:

An error occurred at line: 40 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
XWPFDocument cannot be resolved to a type

An error occurred at line: 40 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
OPCPackage cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: 42 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
XWPFWordExtractor cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: show the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Is that the complete stacktrace?

Comment: also, show what are the import statements that you are using in JSP

Comment: @Mubin Edit my complete stacktrace

Comment: this java code is working as a java application

Comment: Did you import the packages/classes that you are using in your JSP? I think you are missing those imports. Show the import statements of your JSP.

Comment: Do you have the apache-poi jar file in the classpath of your application?

Comment: i have created userlibary of apache-poi jar and added to the class path

Comment: Compile the JSPs manually and check for compilation errors. I believe the jar is not being picked-up properly. Refer to this link for JSP compilation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-0790/6nlqo2pgh/index.html

Comment: yeah adding jar to the lib folder works for me Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jar library was not added properly to the class path

dom4j-1.6.1.jar,
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar,
poi-3.9-20121203.jar,
poi.ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar,
poi.ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar,

placed above jar to the lib

works for me

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you add imports in your jsp and have all requied jars in WEB-INF/lib

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.xmlbeans.*" %>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).